# Wrong number of type arguments: expected 1 but found 0

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to pass a reference of [`std::io::BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) to a function:

```
use std::{fs::File, io::BufReader};

struct CompressedMap;

fn parse_cmp(buf: &mut BufReader) -> CompressedMap {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut buf = BufReader::new(File::open("data/nyc.cmp")?);

    let map = parse_cmp(&mut buf);

    Ok(())
}
```

I get this error message:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
 --> src/main.rs:5:24
  |
5 | fn parse_cmp(buf: &mut BufReader) -> CompressedMap {
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A look at the [implementation of `BufReader`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libstd/io/buffered.rs#L53) makes it clear that `BufReader` has a generic type parameter that must be specified:

```
impl<R: Read> BufReader<R> {
```

Change your function to account for the type parameter. You can allow any generic type:

```
use std::io::Read;

fn parse_cmp<R: Read>(buf: &mut BufReader<R>)
```

You could also use a specific concrete type:

```
fn parse_cmp(buf: &mut BufReader<File>)
```