# How do I make a struct callable?

Tags: rust, implementation, traits

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
#![feature(fn_traits)]

struct foo;

impl std::ops::Add for foo {
    type Output = foo;
    fn add(self, x: foo) -> foo {
        println!("Add for foo");
        x
    }
}

impl Fn for foo {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self) -> Self {
        println!("Call for Foo ");
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = foo;
    let y = foo;
    x + y;

    x();
}
```

I implemented the `Add` trait, but I don't understand how to call the struct as a function. I get the error:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/main.rs:14:10
   |
14 |     impl Fn for foo {
   |          ^^ expected 1 type argument
```

I'm new to Rust, and can't find examples how to make this thing happen.

Answer (score 32):

You cannot yet implement the `Fn*` traits in stable Rust. This is only possible with the nightly compiler using `#[feature]`!

It's very useful to *fully read the trait that you are implementing* to see how to implement it. The [`Fn` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) is defined as:

```
pub trait Fn<Args>: FnMut<Args> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Notice any differences between the implementation and the definition? I see many:

1. The implementation doesn't provide a value for `Args`! That's what the compiler is pointing at. See also [Wrong number of type arguments: expected 1 but found 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25272392/155423)
2. The implementation doesn't implement the supertrait [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), which itself requires the supertrait [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html). `FnOnce` is where the *associated type* `Output` is declared.
3. The implementation neglects to define what concrete type `Output` should be.
4. The implementation returns `Self` while the trait returns `Self::Output`.
5. The implementation doesn't accept the second argument to `call`. This argument contains any arguments passed in.

Additionally, types in Rust use `PascalCase`, not `snake_case`, so it should be `Foo`.

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
#![feature(fn_traits)]

struct Foo;

impl Fn<()> for Foo {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, _args: ()) {
        println!("Call (Fn) for Foo");
    }
}

impl FnMut<()> for Foo {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, _args: ()) {
        println!("Call (FnMut) for Foo");
    }
}

impl FnOnce<()> for Foo {
    type Output = ();

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _args: ()) {
        println!("Call (FnOnce) for Foo");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Foo;
    x();
}
```

Normally though, only one trait's implementation would have interesting code in it and the other trait implementations would delegate to it:

```
extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: ()) {
    println!("Foo called, took args: {:?}", args);
}

// ...

extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: ()) {
    self.call(args)
}

// ...

extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: ()) {
    self.call(args)
}
```

See also:

- [What is a crate attribute and where do I add it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27454761/155423)

Answer (score 9):

By implementing Deref, you can simulate the desired behavior. Then you just use parentheses around parameters and get a return value just like you were calling a function.

See this thread: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/callable-struct-on-stable/54689/6

The relevant part (thanks to crawdad):

```rust
fn main() {
    let func: Functionish = make_func();
    func();
}

fn make_func() -> Functionish {
    Functionish {
        f: Box::new(|| println!("printing")),
    }
}

struct Functionish {
    f: Box<dyn Fn()>,
}

impl std::ops::Deref for Functionish {
    type Target = dyn Fn();

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.f
    }
}
```

Here is an incomplete example from my own code that takes parameters, one a ref and one a mutable ref. In my case, the closure is stored inside an Rc, which necessitated the odd line `&(*self.function_container)` because I need to go into the Rc before I can get the reference to the closure.

```
pub struct FeelFunction {
  pub function_type: FunctionType,
  name_container: RefCell<String>,
  function_container: Rc<dyn Fn(&FeelValue, &mut NestedContext) -> FeelValue>
}

impl Deref for FeelFunction {
  type Target = dyn Fn(&FeelValue, &mut NestedContext) -> FeelValue;

  fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
      &(*self.function_container)
  }
}
```