# How to return an Option<_, _> from a getter method on a struct?

Tags: rust, struct, option-type

I've applied generics to a struct and want to get its output in an `Option<_, _>` type using a getter method implemented on the struct.

```
struct Point<T, U> {
    x: T,
    y: U,
}
impl<T, U> Point<T, U> {
    fn x(&self) -> Option<T, U> {
        let z = &self.x;
        z.get(5);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Point { x: 5, y: 10.0 };
    println!("p.x = {}", p.x());
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c00b9bc2e7932667e64d0cf5aabfaf74))

The output of the above mentioned code is

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 2
 --> src/main.rs:6:30
  |
6 |     fn x(&self) -> Option<T, U> {
  |                              ^ unexpected type argument
```

Comment: `Option<T>` only takes one type argument, so what do you want when you're using `Option<T, U>`?

Comment: What do you want the printout to say? I don't understand what you intend the result of `p.x()` to be.

Answer (score 3):

Take the time to read the documentation for the types you are using. [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) only has one generic type:

```
pub enum Option<T> {
    None,
    Some(T),
}
```

As an educated guess, you likely meant to use a [tuple](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#the-tuple-type):

```
fn x(&self) -> Option<(T, U)> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Other possibilities are [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html):

```
fn x(&self) -> Result<T, U> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Or perhaps [`Either`](https://docs.rs/either/1.5.3/either/enum.Either.html):

```
fn x(&self) -> either::Either<T, U> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

See also:

- [fn foo() -> Result<()> throws "expected 2 type arguments"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53584631/155423)
- [Wrong number of type arguments: expected 1 but found 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25272392/155423)

---

Your code has a number of problems that will prevent it from compiling:

- You cannot return owned `T` or `U` types in a method that takes `&self` without performing some kind of copying / cloning.
- You cannot call a method (`get`) on a generic type without some kind of trait bounds. The method doesn't even seem to be defined.
- You cannot format a tuple with the `Display` formatter.

Comment: I think he actually wants `Either`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman indeed! Since `get` isn't defined, it's even harder to guess.

Comment: @Shepmaster Is there any method named get() in rust prelude?

Comment: @FawadAhmed you can see [all the methods in the Rust standard library named `get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=get) and the contents of [the prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html) . That being said, **you** wrote this code, so shouldn't **you** know what that `get` is supposed to be?

Comment: @Shepmaster That is what I'm confused with. Thanks for correcting me.